# Registry under HKEY LOCAL_MACHINE is not working

Tags: windows, windows-registry, dpi

I needed to override DPI setting value in the windows machine of my Java swing application. For that, I needed to create registry key following path.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
```

In side the Layers key, I created string registry where value is "~DPIUNAWARE". It's worked as expected.

I needed to add the same registry value in to the `LOCAL_MACHINE` instead of CURRENT_USER. I removed previously created registry under `CURRENT_USER` and created new registry under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
```

But it's not worked as expected. What could be the issue?

Since my application architecture is 32 bit version, I try to create same registry key under following path also.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
```

It's also not worked. ?

Comment: Do you have multiple users on this machine?  If you only have a single users modifying `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` should be more than enough.  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` is only required if the machine has multiple users.  if this is for an application you are trying to author, you should modify, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and ``HKEY_CURRENT_USER` depending on the key a reboot will be required to introduce the change.  It's not clear the reason you need to modify `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` though.  Please edit your question to make that point clear.

Comment: yes, this application is using more than one users different times in same machine. That is why I just wanted to add this registry in to Local_Machine rather than Current_User